# When does foreach call .combine?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have written some code using `foreach` which processes and combines a large number of CSV files. I am running it on a 32 core machine, using `%dopar%` and registering 32 cores with `doMC`. I have set `.inorder=FALSE`, `.multicombine=TRUE`, `verbose=TRUE`, and have a custom combine function.

I notice if I run this on a sufficiently large set of files, it appears that R attempts to process EVERY file before calling .combine the first time. My evidence is that in monitoring my server with htop, I initially see all cores maxed out, and then for the remainder of the job only one or two cores are used while it does the combines in batches of ~100 (`.maxcombine`'s default), as seen in the verbose console output. What's really telling is the more jobs i give to foreach, the longer it takes to see "First call to combine"!

This seems counter-intuitive to me; I naively expected foreach to process `.maxcombine` files, combine them, then move on to the next batch, combining those with the output of the last call to `.combine`. I suppose for most uses of `.combine` it wouldn't matter as the output would be roughly the same size as the sum of the sizes of inputs to it; however my combine function pares down the size a bit. My job is large enough that I could not possibly hold all 4200+ individual foreach job outputs in RAM simultaneously, so I was counting on my space-saving `.combine` and separate batching to see me through.

Am I right that .combine doesn't get called until ALL my `foreach` jobs are individually complete? If so, why is that, and how can I optimize for that (other than making the output of each job smaller) or change that behavior?

Comment: My understanding is that parallel execution occurs in batches; that `foreach` will distribute lists in bundles of length(parList)/ncores. I suppose combining partial results might be useful as a space saving measure. You may get more control with the `iter` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is to use either `doMPI` or `doRedis` as your parallel backend.  They work more as you expect.

The `doMC`, `doSNOW` and `doParallel` backends are relatively simple wrappers around functions such as `mclapply` and `clusterApplyLB`, and don't call the combine function until all of the results have been computed, as you've observed.  The `doMPI`, `doRedis`, and (now defunct) `doSMP` backends are more complex, and get inputs from the iterators as needed and call the combine function on-the-fly, as you have assumed they would.  These backends have a number of advantages in my opinion, and allow you to handle an arbitrary number of tasks if you have appropriate iterators and combine function.  It surprises me that so many people get along just fine with the simpler backends, but if you have a lot of tasks, the fancy ones are essential, allowing you to do things that are quite difficult with packages such as `parallel`.

I've been thinking about writing a more sophisticated backend based on the `parallel` package that would handle results on the fly like my `doMPI` package, but there's hasn't been any call for it to my knowledge.  In fact, yours has been the only question of this sort that I've seen.

---

*Update*

The `doSNOW` backend now supports on-the-fly result handling. Unfortunately, this can't be done with `doParallel` because the `parallel` package doesn't export the necessary functions.

Comment: Well don't take my inquiry as evidence of a serious need in the community; this is my first task of anywhere near this scope so I really have no idea what I'm doing (yet). I managed to crash my 32-core, 128GB R server! Processed all 4914 files, then kernel panicked  while summarizing post-foreach. Time for a code rewrite. 
In looking at the intros for `doMPI` and `doRedis`, I'll be trying yours if I cant get around my issue in some other way. Thanks for both this answer and all the work you've done on these awesome packages!

Comment: @Steve, is this still true?  Revolutions released an v1.0.7 of the `doParallel` package with the comment:

    1.0.7  2014-02-01
        o  Modified to work better when a foreach loop is executed 
           in a package (courtesy of Steve Weston)
        o  Added unit tests and a minimal working example

Comment: @ChristopherBrown Yes, it's still true. Adding support for on-the-fly result handling would be tricky since the underlying packages don't really support returning results on-the-fly, and the parallel package doesn't even export the internal functions that might allow that to be added to a modified version of clusterApplyLB.